# amsart maketitle problem

Tags: titles, amsart

I am editing a paper using amsart documentclass. However, the

```
\maketitle
```

command does not give me the author and abstract. My codes are here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,latexsym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\title{MyTitle}
\author{MyAuthor}
\begin{abstract}
MyAbstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
Text
\end{document}
```

And the resulting file only have  "MyTitle" as title and "Text" as text. Author and abstract information are missing.

How can I add adstract and authors by using maketitle?

Comment: Remove the `titling` package. I don't know why this is an issue (yet), but that's the problem.  (Also, as a matter of style, I would put the metadata (title/author) before `\begin{document}`, and I would put `\maketitle` before your abstract. **Edit:** it appears to be a package conflict and not a problem with `titling` itself.

Comment: @SeanAllred the [amsart.tex](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/amslatex/classes/amsart.template) template recommends `abstract` before `\maketitle`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I stand corrected -- good to know!

Comment: @SeanAllred you should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @SeanAllred Your suggestion works! The problem is solved after I removed the titling package. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

While I *still* can't pinpoint the source of the problem, removing the `titling` package resolves the issue. It appears to be a package clash, but with what—I do not know yet.

Comment: The `titling` package redefines `\maketitle`, so all `amsart` would do with it is forgotten. In particular the abstract vanishes (`titling` doesn't know about printing it) and also the authors, because `amsart` *doesn't* use `\@author` as the internal container.

Comment: As of 2023, the TeX Live bundle Debian/2022 still has the 2009 version of `titling`, and the issue persists.