# Moving title up in amsart

Tags: titles, amsart

I am writing an article using the `amsart` format (the American Mathematical Society's article format).

For example, I would write:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\title{My title} 

\author{My name}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Hi

\end{document}
```

I find that this format puts the title/author heading quite low on the first page, and I would like to move it up a bit.

If I use the article format instead of `amsart`, I usually have a few hacks that work to do this.

One is to `\usepackage{titling}` and then add `\setlength{\droptitle}{-3em}` to my preamble. This doesn't work in `amsart`, since the titling package completely messes up the title. (See [amsart maketitle problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130103/amsart-maketitle-problem?rq=1))

Another is to just add some negative space in my title, like:

```
\title{\vspace{-1cm}My title}
```

But this appears to have no effect in `amsart`.

Does anyone have a simple trick for this?

Comment: if you are using amsart because you like the look then do whatever you wish, but if you are using amsart to subbmit a paper to the AMS don't do this! The whole point of publisher styles is to enforce a house style and remove style choices from the author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put `\vspace*{-1cm}` before `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\title{My title} 
\author{My name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{-1cm}

\maketitle

Hi

\end{document}
```

The simple `\vspace{-1cm}` doesn't work, because `\vspace` commands that follow a page break disappear; the start of a document is considered to happen after a page break (for uniformity). On the contrary, `\vspace*` is never removed at page breaks.

Comment: I didn't know about vspace* ! What does the * do that makes that work while vspace doesn't? Regardless, thanks very much.

Comment: @user145149 I added the explanation.